# How add custom text after PayPal express checkout button on product page woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

when I add custom text/html to product page I use this code on function.php

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'after_cart_function');
function after_cart_function() {
    echo "my text";
}
```

the problem is the text show before paypal express checkout button,
I like to add after paypal button

I have already try the others hook without success

Comment: _"I have already try the others hook without success"_ - Which hooks? 
Have you tried adjusting the priority of the current hook? have you checked the source code to see if the output of this hook is right before the output code of the paypal button? 
How was that paypal button added?

Comment: Which PayPal plugin is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it after the PayPal button, you need to use this code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'after_cart_function', 1000);
function after_cart_function() {
    echo "my text";
}
```

Edit: You can use the plugin "[Simply Show Hooks](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/simply-show-hooks/)" to check where to hook.